# Laravel eloquent get data with current user logged in

Tags: mysql, laravel

So I have two models.

> CodeModel - i will get data here with the current user logged in
>
> MemberModel - this is my user model

In my CodeModel i have

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MemberModel ', 'member_id');
}
```

and in my MemberModel

```
public function codes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CodeModel ', 'member_id');
}
```

STRUCTURE:

```
tbl_members
---------------
id | username |
---------------
1  |  user1   |

tbl_codes
-------------------------
id | member_id |  code  |
-------------------------
1  |    1      |  qew1  |
-------------------------
```

So in my Controller I want to get tbl_codes data with the current user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I hope when you log in you might be saving the logged in user details like name, id in session. So get the details from the session while querying like the follwing

```
/* The following code must be written in controller */
/* Here I am getting all the details of the member details from the session and storing in member details */

$memberDetails = $request->session()->get('memberDetails');

/* Get the member details from the session array */
$memberId = $memberDetails['id']; //or $memberDetails->id based on your details storage in the session

$tblCodeDetails = Models\TblCode::where('member_id', $memberId)->get();
```